# JVM Used heap grows while has an internet connection

Tags: java, memory, jvm, heap-memory

I stumbled upon this by accident while trying to debug a memory leak in an applicaiton. The network that my computer was attched to was being migrated and when the switch was unplugged the JVM used heap stopped growing.

When the computer has an active network connection the memory used by the JVM grows (it will eventually get GC). This works on java programs which both have and dont have internet connections.

Example.java:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while (true){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you run Visual VM you will notice that the memory used grows steadily. If you were to disconnect from you network it flat lines.

I unfortunaly cannot upload an image as the netowork wont allow me.

Why is this?

EDIT: If the cable is reattached the used heap will start to grow again

Answer (score 1):

VisualVM uses quite a bit of memory to operate.  It makes a number of RMI calls via JMX which produces quite a bit of garbage.

Some of these calls check the DNS name of of IP addresses being used so when you pull the network out, most likely you are stopping it from operating or causing it to timeout slowing it's sampling rate down dramatically.

You can configure VisualVM to sample less often, but you can also use a profiler which doesn't create as much garbage.

BTW To test a program not doing anything I use

```
System.in.read();
```

To monitor the memory usage in a more light weight way you can use `jstat -gcusage {pid}`  This will produce less garbage.